# Hibernate foreign key and primary key in one table using one-to-one mapping

Tags: hibernate, orm, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I am beginner to hibernate, just have a doubt,
Could you please help me to design following relations

```
Employee table
`Eid - primary key`
`ename`
`esal`

Address
`aid` - primary key
addressLine1
city
state
eid - foreign key of employee table
```

It is having one to one relationship, Employee has only one address.

How can I manage primary and foreign key in one table using one-to-one mapping in hibernate.
What could be the xml mappings for this relation in hibernate.

```
Tried


employee
<class name="Employee" table="employee" schema="system">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="ename" />
        <property name="designation" column="designation" />
        <one-to-one name="address" class="Address" cascade="all"/>      
    </class>


Address
<class name="Address" table="address_details" schema="system">      
        <id name="eid" column="id">
            <generator class="increment">               
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="address" column="address"></property>
        <property name="city" column="city"></property>
        <property name="state" column="state"></property>
        <one-to-one name="emp" class="Employee" column="eid"></one-to-one>
    </class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find tons of examples on the internet. This particular model is even showcases here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne